# uses-feature required=false in manifest.xml not compiling on android 1.6

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have a problem with my app, the new market feature added the "uses feature" implicitly, for the wifi feature.
the wifi feature in my app is optional, so I wanted to add

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" android:required="false" />
```

but, now the app does not compile (using SDK version 5 for android 1.6)

AndroidManifest.xml:52: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'required' in package 'android'

AndroidManifest.xml:52: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'required' in package 'android'

Answer (score 7):

The `android:required` attribute was added in API level 5 (Android 2.0). Since you are using the 1.6 SDK, it has no idea what it is, hence the error.

As a general rule, don't use old SDKs. Always use the latest and set the [`<uses-sdk>`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html) attributes appropriately.